# How to retrieve the UiElement generated by the datatemplate?

Tags: wpf

I have a listBox:

```
<ListBox Name="myListBox" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myDataTemplate}"
     IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
<ListBox.ItemsSource>
  <Binding Source="{StaticResource InventoryData}" XPath="Books/Book"/>
</ListBox.ItemsSource>
</ListBox>
```

With the following datatemplete:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myDataTemplate">
<TextBlock Name="textBlock" FontSize="14" Foreground="Blue">
  <TextBlock.Text>
   <Binding XPath="Title"/>
 </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

How to retrieve the UiElement generated by the datatemplate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to retrieve the TextBlock element generated by the DataTemplate of a certain ListBoxItem, you need to get the ListBoxItem, find the ContentPresenter within that ListBoxItem, and then call FindName on the DataTemplate that is set on that ContentPresenter. The following example shows how to perform those steps. For demonstration purposes, this example creates a message box that shows the text content of the DataTemplate-generated text block.

```
// Getting the currently selected ListBoxItem
// Note that the ListBox must have
// IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem set to True for this to work
ListBoxItem myListBoxItem =
     (ListBoxItem)    (myListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(myListBox.Items.CurrentItem));

// Getting the ContentPresenter of myListBoxItem
ContentPresenter myContentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(myListBoxItem);

// Finding textBlock from the DataTemplate that is set on that ContentPresenter
DataTemplate myDataTemplate = myContentPresenter.ContentTemplate;
TextBlock myTextBlock = (TextBlock)myDataTemplate.FindName("textBlock",     myContentPresenter);
```